# Python: How to combine 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to combine two numpy arrays so they look like this

the input is:

```
a = np.arange(3).reshape(3)
b = np.arange(3).reshape(3)
```

and combine a and b so it looks like this:

```
[[0 , 0], [0 , 1],[0 , 2],[1 , 0],[1 , 1],[1 , 2],[2 , 0],[2 , 1],[2 , 2]]
```

Comment: You're looking for a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

This is the trivial solution:

```
res = np.array([[i, j] for i in a for j in b])
```